# How to impersonate a WCF REST service

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-client

How to impersonate the WCF REST service:

HttpWebResponse response;

```
        HttpWebRequest request;

        try
        {
            request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TransferUrl"] + "/Download/" + ID1 + "/" + ID2 );

            request.Method = "GET";

            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        }
```

Is it possible to do it even in the code in the service

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Is this for a unit test or something?

Comment: I also need same. Did you get this working...

Answer (score 0):

A few ways come to mind:

- Use a Mocking framework (e.g. [Rhino Mocks](http://hibernatingrhinos.com/open-source/rhino-mocks)) to replace the calls.
- Put your client proxy behind an interface so you can specify the behavior at runtime.  In other words, in production your code will hit the service, in test you hit some test implementation you've put together.
- Point your client towards a test implementation of the REST service.